# Does a recursive procedure "recur"?

Tags: programming, computing

In programming, a recursive procedure is defined as a procedure which refers to itself in the code. The question is, is "recur" the corresponding verb to the adjective "recursive"? Can I say that a recursive procedure "recurs"?

Comment: Actually, it's common to say it _recurses._

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that was a verb. I assumed recursion came from recur.

Comment: That's all I wanted to know, actually, could you put that as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: It looks like the modern use of *recurse* is a back-formation from *recursion*, which came from *recur*. But *recurse* is still the correct word here.

Comment: Recur > Recursion > Recurse, you say?

Comment: Yes, it means to damn the bugs once again.

Comment: ...That was a joke right :P

Comment: When I looked up "recursive" in the dictionary, all it said was "See **recursive**"

Comment: When I've unintentionally caused a program to go into recursion I have often cursed and then recursed, but the program only recurred.

Comment: If found _"to recurse"_ (intransitive verb) in "The Joy of Clojure, 2nd edition" (Michael Fogus, Chris Houser, Manning, May 2014, p. 37). That's definitely a neologism, if not a cyberiadism. Back when I went to school, we said "the function calls itself" or "the function performs a recursive call". As in _"a recursive function is simply a function which calls itself"_ (Functional Programming, Anthony J. Field, Peter G. Harrison, Addison-Wesley Publishers Ltd, 1988, p. 19)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it does **[recur](http://i.word.com/idictionary/recur)**.

According to Wiktionary, [recurse](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/recurse) is a back formation from recursion.

Google [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recur%2Crecursive%2Crecurse&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crecur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecursive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecurse%3B%2Cc0) shows that recur is the base word, with recurse as a new invention.

Comment: It seems to me that *recurse* is a necessary back-formation, as *recur*, while applicable, is ambiguous. A recurrent process could recur, but iteratively or driven by events, rather than recursively. Only a recursive process can recurse.

Comment: ... Which means you're correct but I doubt it's the right answer the OP is looking for.

Comment: Ah, greetings @Chris! I haven't spent much time over here for ages. Yes, I notice the OP hasn't selected an answer; sometimes the technically correct answer just doesn't sit right with a given person (it's happened to me too). It's hard to say anything is *necessary*, *correct*, or *ambiguous* in language though, since it's always changing. The textbooks can only describe what *was*. Nice to see you in a different context.

Comment: Greetings to you too @Andy256. I find the "usage" part of this site particularly interesting, especially when it comes to technical usage, so I think it's a decent question and I like both answers. Which for some reason appeared months after the question was posted.

Comment: @Chris The community process periodically pokes questions that don't have an accepted answer, bringing them to the front of the activity queue.

Comment: The need for a verb like "recurse" stems from cumbersome phrases like *"this function will recursively call itself"*. "Recur" doesn't fit here, while, intuitively, something like *"this function will recurse"* would be just fine, if existed. So, we've just went ahead and created it, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

"Recur" is the proper word for this procedure while "recurse" is technically not a word by most dictionaries.  There are many verbs without an "s" at the end which gain an "s" in the adjective form.  Here are some examples:

> submit -> submissive
>
> corrode -> corrosive
>
> abrade -> abrasive
>
> adhere -> adhesive

Naturally, "recur" follows the same pattern.

> recur -> recursive

Because your function recurs, or occurs again, it is recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a recursive function recurses. You can expect that a recursive function will recurse multiple times.

Here is an example in Java, that really hammers the concept home:

```
public void curse(){
    System.out.println("F$%& You!!");
    curse();
}
```

[image: Recursing]